# Alinear imagenes de Productos en tienda WooCommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theme

la verdad le he dado muchas vueltas al CSS de mi tienda para alinear correctamente las miniaturas que salen en la pagina principal de mi tienda WooCommerce.

El tema que uso es Ascend de Kaddence Themes aunque muy modificado, el css no lo puedo adjuntar porque yo uso la consola de Google Chrome

https://bellpro.cl/tienda

Answer (score 0):

Buenas,

Veo que la parrilla se carga con Masonry (https://masonry.desandro.com/). Este script hace que en la carga de los productos la parrrilla encaje perfectamente en el cómputo global de forma automática, independientemente de la altura que tengan los elementos, pero no tienes el control de cómo lo hace, ya que cambia en función al ancho y altura de cada contenido. 
Es un script muy útil para no denavarse los sesos con la maquetación responsive cuando tienes muchos elementos que encajar con diferentes alturas.

Si quieres que estén alineadas horizontalmente, tendrás que deshacerte de este script y utilizar otro sistema por filas de alto fijo o bien ser muy cuidadoso con que la "imagen + descripción" siempre tenga la misma altura, aunque esta forma no te la recomiendo.

Espero haberte servido de ayuda. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola @Daniel Romeo, por lo visto debo cambiar el script que ordena las imagenes, existe alguna recomendación? Ya que mi plantilla usa Masonry por defecto tiene que haber otro framework que haga la carga con alineamiento no? Porque he intentado alinearlo yo por CSS pero es que cada elemento tiene una clase diferente entonces tendria que asignarle el css que quiero a cada producto y no lo veo factible... De todas formas muchas gracias, veremos si alguien sabe qué solucion pueda ser la mas efectiva, saludos!

Comment: Hola Matías,
Modificando el css desde consola no vas a conseguir dar con una solución. Para solucionarlo sin tener que cambiar de plantilla, tendrías que dar con el archivo que genera los artículos en tu aplicación wordpress y modificar desde ahí la parte de código que genera los elementos de parrilla. Otra opción es hacer como hacen en la demo de la plantilla que usas (http://themes.kadencethemes.com/ascend-premium-3/shop/) y que el título del producto en ningún caso pase de una linea.
Un saludo.

Comment: En ese eCommerce no veo disitinción entre título y descripción del producto. Lo aconsejable sería que el título del producto fuera muy escueto y dentro de la ficha se detallaran el resto de datos, como descripción del producto. Un saludo.

Comment: Lo se, pero no puedo hacer nada, el cliente quiere los títulos así. He mirado en la demo de la plantilla y cambiando el titulo a uno exageradamente grande siguen alineados en cambio en mi tienda se desalinean.

Comment: Hola Matías, prueba a añadir este css desde el inspector y redimensionar la ventana para que Masonry actúe y vuelva a reposicionar los elementos:

.product_item .product_archive_title {
    height: 200px;
}

Verás que ahora quedarán (exagerádamente) alineados a excepción del margen que crean los precios. Esto es porque no todos los artículos tienen precio, pero imagino que la idea es que lo tengan.

He puesto 200px a modo exagerado, pero calcula la altura máxima que pueda tener el título más largo y reposiciona el precio (.price) para que quede tras el título.

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias Daniel, voy a estar trasteando las clases .price .product_item .product_archive_title de verdad me has ayudado muchisimo!